# Display Maximum Call count from table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 1 Mysql Table having fields Mobile No. Toll free Number
There are 4 Toll free number in a 1 day and any user will call on the toll free number and system will store that mob number against the toll free number.

What i want is below:
A user should call to all toll free number and display count of mobile calls against each toll free number.
Note: Result will display only if user has called on each toll free number.

How to write MySQL query for this situation?

I'm trying from last 3 days.

I have wrote below query:

```
SELECT * from table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b on b.mobile = a.mobile
INNER JOIN table3 c on c.mobile = a.mobile
INNER JOIN table4 d on d.mobile = a.mobile
INNER JOIN master_table m on m.tfn_no = a.tf_no 
$whereclause 
group by a.mobile LIMIT 0,10
```

Kindly provide me the solution.
I have used view for this situation. So created view of 4 toll free number with 4 views and applied inner join to each view. Kindly correct me for the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using MySQL's aggregate functions such as `MAX()` and `COUNT()`. Using aliases could also be helpful.

Comment: Hi Fred,I want if mobile number 1234567890 has called 5 times in Toll free Number 1 and same mobile number has called 3 times in toll free no.2 and 2 times in toll free no.3 and 10 times in toll free no.4.
How to write down query for that?

Comment: You can use `HAVING` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx along with `COUNT()`.